# QGIS installation from OSGeoW4: entry point not found in qgis_core.dll

Tags: qgis, error, installation, osgeo4w

I have installed QGIS through OSGeo4W installation. My operation system is windows 7 64x. I try to start the program QGIS Desktop from start menu this error:
 [image]

Do I need to do something? Installation was successful and re installing doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you have any previous version installed using stand-alone installer on the same system?

Comment: @underdark Yes, I have installed but I uninstalled it and tried to delete every track from that stand-alone installer

Comment: @undertake I cleaned my system completely from the previous installation and installed again and it is resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by leftovers of previous QGIS installs. Clean up everything and QGIS should work again.

Answer (score 0):

qgishelp continues to run in the background when quitting QGis and even after uninstall / install process, which prevents some files from being replaced. Therefore run task manager and kill that process before installing.