# DLL problem with QGIS 3.0 64bit (while 32bit works)

Tags: qgis, installation, windows, qgis-3, dll

I installed the new version of QGIS 3.0 and first of all it worked all fine. After a while I tried to launch QGIS again and now the following problem appears.[image: Problem-DLL]

After clicking "OK" another window appears:
[image: DLL]

So I opened the .env-file and it says:

```
    PATH=C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\Scripts;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qt5\bin;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\OSGEO4~1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem
GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGEO4~1\share\gdal
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins
GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
JPEGMEM=1000000
OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGEO4~1
PROJ_LIB=C:\OSGEO4~1\share\proj
PYTHONHOME=C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36
QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis
QT_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\qtplugins;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qt5\plugins
QT_RASTER_CLIP_LIMIT=4096
VSI_CACHE=TRUE
VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
```

What I have done so far:
1. uninstalling the program and reinstalling several times via Standalone-installer aswell as the OSGEO4W-installation - also tried the three different server and with Administrator-rights (as described in [Problem starting QGIS 2.14, Prozedureinsprungpunkt is not found](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207606))
2. uninstalled and cleaned the registry-data as described in  [How to completely uninstall and remove QGIS 2.8.1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152873/)
3. I searched for a duplicate of the Qt5Sql.dll that appeared another time in my Teamspeak-folder > so I uninstalled Teamspeak
4. Searched for leftovers from old versions and deleted all
5. uninstalled the QGIS-version via the OSGEO4W-installer and deleted the OSGEO4W-folder
6. installed the 3.0 (32-bit version) and later the 2.18.18-LTR version (no problems appeared there)

If anyone has another idea how to solve the problem, I am happy for your help!